# Exception occurred while fetching Azure certificate

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services

I am working on a windows service which will call `Microsoft Azure Management Libraries` for managing cloud services. But while doing so my program is not returning the credentials, which is used to manage cloud activities. When I tested the same code in Console Application it worked fine every time, but when I integrated the code with Windows Services, the function which is used to fetch the credentials is giving the exception `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the >>collection. Parameter name: index`. 
I don't why this code is not behaving correctly while returning the certificate. But the exception is occurred due to the class `X509Certificate2Collection` which is unable to find the certificate and return a collection. Hence my code fails. My Questions are:

> > 1. Can anyone tell me what is the possible solution to solve this above discussed error.
> > 2. Why my code is behaving differently when I integrated the same code in Windows Service?

For reference http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries

//Code

```
internal class CertificateAuthenticationHelper
{
    internal static SubscriptionCloudCredentials GetCredentials(
        string subscrtionId,
        string thumbprint)
    {
        return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscrtionId, GetCertificate(thumbprint));
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint)
    {
        X509Store certStore = null;
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = null;
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

        // Open the certificate store for the current user.
        certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        //certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        // Find the certificate with the specified thumbprint.
        certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                             X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                             thumbprint,
                             false);
        certStore.Close();
        // A matching certificate was found.
// Here I am getting exception as my function is unable to find any matching certificate. 
//I checked my certCollection.Count which is 0 in Windows Service. But when I am debugging the same code in Console Application its returning 1. 
            certificate = certCollection[0];
            return certificate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your Windows Service running on the same machine from where you ran the Console Application? Also see under which user context your Windows Service is running.

Comment: yeah its using same machine and same account

Comment: Please try something: First, put the certificate in `LocalMachine` store instead of `CurrentUser` and then change your code to read from `LocalMachine` store. See if that works.

Comment: I'll try this and let you informed thanks Gaurav

Comment: Awesome. What did you end up doing? Adding certificate to `LocalMachine` store?

Comment: My service was not reading certificate from `current user` instead I tried keeping certificate in `LocalComputer` and changed code to read from that location (LocalComputer) as you suggested and it worked :)

Comment: Cool! Let me put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the management certificate in `LocalMachine` certificate store instead of `CurrentUser` store and change the code accordingly to read from `LocalMachine` store.

As you can see from the error message, your Windows Service is not able to find that certificate in `CurrentUser` store. Most likely it is because the Windows Service is running under a different user context.